# Geolocator won't ask for permission on iOS flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my app I use `geolocator: ^6.0.0-rc.3` package but since I upgraded to this version app is stuck with `LocationPermission.deniedForever` even dough I granted permission.
[image]

I have put a check to ask for permission but the permission popup doesn't appear.
Can you spot what I'm doing wrong here?
As always many thanks.

```
await geolocator.checkPermission().then((LocationPermission value) async {
      print('GeolocatorDevice.getPosition() getPosition device checkPermission : $value');
      // prints 'flutter: GeolocatorDevice.getPosition() getPosition device checkPermission : LocationPermission.deniedForever'

      if(value == null || value == LocationPermission.denied || value == LocationPermission.deniedForever ) {
        print('GeolocatorDevice.getPosition() will now request permission');
        await geolocator.requestPermission().then((value) async {
          locationPermission = value;

        }).catchError((e) => print('GeolocatorDevice.getPosition() requestPermission error: $e'));
      } else {
        locationPermission = value;

        await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        )
            .timeout(Duration(seconds: 100))
            .then((value) {
          position = value;
          print('GeolocatorDevice.getPosition() location is $value');
        }).catchError((e) => print('GeolocatorDevice.getPosition() Error fetching user position : $e'));
      }

    });
```

Comment: I am having this same issue. Please do share your solution if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

Did you implement in `AndroidManifest.xml` located under path `android -> app -> src -> main` the permissions for android access like this ?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourCompanyName.whateverNameHaveYourProject">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <application
    .....
    .....
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Also in `Info.plist` located under path `ios -> Runner` you need to add the next permission for iOS side like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
.....
.....
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Needed to access location always when the app is open.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Needed to access location when the app is open and run in background.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```